# JSHint displays a warning, not sure why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I stumbled upon this very useful jQuery script, which adds CSS inline backgrounds for blocks of text. It works great, but when I run it through CodeKit/JSHint I get the following warning:

```
 var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
'options' is already defined. — column 18
```

Here's the jQuery code, it works - I'm just curios as to why CodeKit/JSHint would display this warning?

```
/*!
* jQuery Typographic Background Plugin
* http://owenmelbourne.com
*
* Copyright 2012, Owen Melbourne || Selesti Ltd
* Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses.
* http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
* http://www.opensource.org/licenses/GPL-2.0
*/

(function($){
 $.fn.typographicbg = function(options) {

 var defaults = {
   padding: '5px',
  };
 var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

return this.each(function() {

  var selector = $(this);
  var padding = options.padding;

  $(selector).each(function(){

  // Wrapping Words in Spans for padding application
        var string = $(this).text().split(' ');
        var word = $(this);
        $(this).text('');
        $.each(string, function(){
            word.append('<span>'+this+' </span>');
        });

        $(this).find('span').css({'padding-top': padding, 'padding-bottom': padding});
        $(this).find('span:first-child').css('padding-left', padding);
        $(this).find('span:last-child').css('padding-right', padding);

        var startingheight = $(this).find('span').position().top;
        $(this).find('span').each(function(){

        var thisheight = $(this).position().top;

//Apply the padding to new lines and previous
            if (thisheight > startingheight) {
            $(this).attr('data-ypos','height is: '+thisheight);
            startingheight = thisheight;
            $(this).css('padding-left', padding);
            $(this).prev().css('padding-right', padding);
            }


        });


    });

}); 
}; 
})(jQuery);

/* End Plugin Code */

// Run the plugin on .news-caption 
$(function(){
$('.news-caption').typographicbg({padding: '5px'});
});
```

Here's a link to the original JSfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/OwenMelbz/rd8Qc/

Credit: http://owenmelbourne.com/

Comment: You're passing `options` as an argument, therefore you can't assign it as a new variable.

Comment: Nothing *wrong* with it, just that the inner declaration of `options` is hiding the parameter `options` and it may not be so obvious at first glance. Best practice is to create a newly named variable.

Comment: rename your function arguments args

Comment: It wouldn't display the warning with `options = ..`', without `var`, because `options` is already defined, as function parameter.

Comment: @dsuckau That would change the `options` object passed in, which may not be expected by the caller.